# Span inside h2 - can't apply inline styles

Tags: html, css

I have this title on my page:

```
<h2 style='color:#33bbff;'>Los Angeles, <span style='font-size:10px;color:black;'>Unites States</span></h2>
```

As you see I want the country to be a different color and size from the city. Now, I've done similar things probably a hundred times, but for some reason the span styles aren't applied here - the country looks just like the city. What am I doing wrong?

I tried writing the styles like h2 span { ... } instead of doing them inline, didn't help.

Comment: That [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ZL7/). Something else must be overriding your `span` styles.

Comment: Do you have any `!important`s in your stylesheet?

Comment: works fine in jsfiddle.net. What browser are you using?

Comment: it is absolutely working code, may be you have to close the browser open with other broswer/ restart your browser!

Comment: Unable to comment so writing as answer.
Try using chrome developer tools (check the css part of 'united states' using inspect element), or any other such feature of the browser you are using. Just to be clear, I hope by "I have this title on my page:" you are not referring to title tag!

Comment: it works for me, problem will be somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code appears to be fine (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eezgY/)).

Perhaps you've cached the old version. In your test browser, hit CTRL+F5 to force a reload of all files.

Otherwise, try checking if you've made use of the `!important;` to force a style and ignore other styles.

Comment: I wouldn't use `!important` just because I can't figure something out. There is an underlying problem that needs fixed.

Comment: cache is a web developer's second biggest nightmare.

Comment: @ericosg What's the first?

Comment: duh. IE. :P @yarian

Answer (score 0):

Debug it by using a **Developer Tool Bar** e.g. *FireBug*, and trace the styling applied, maybe something else is overriding the style. ( http://jsfiddle.net/unVNN/ )

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake, simply delete cash in your browser, CTRL+F5